# db_select returns empty array, BUT the raw query returns records...?

Tags: 7

I've written a query to get records that `start` column is later than a given time. Take the following:

```
$q = db_select('timetable_slot', 's')
    ->fields('s')
    ->where('str_to_date(s.start, \'%H:%i\') >= \'15:24\' ');

    print_r($q->__toString());
    /* SELECT s.* FROM timetable_slot s WHERE (str_to_date(s.start, '%H:%i') >= '15:24' ) */


$result = $q->execute()
    ->fetchAll();

print_r($result); /* [] */
```

`$result` comes back as an empty array.
If I run the generated SQL manually I get the results I expect, any reason why drupal is returning an empty set?

I've also tried:

```
db_query("SELECT s.* FROM {timetable_slot} s WHERE (str_to_date(s.start, '%H:%i') > '15:24')")->fetchAll();
```

This also returns empty, even though the query works in a db client.

Thanks

Comment: Try `->where('str_to_date(s.start, \'%%H:%%i\') >= \'15:24\' ');`, with the double percent signs

Comment: Thanks for the response @Clive, that doesn't look to have changed anything. :|

Comment: Do you really need all fields?  Try naming them in your `->fields` argument.  I know it is supposed to default to * when only given a table alias, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to troubleshoot such a query without access to your environment.

The [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) has a query inspection tool (**Display query log** in the Devel settings). that can assist you in determining what query was sent to your database. Use that to determine the exact query sent to your DB and  how it differs from the query you're sending to your SQL client.

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for the response. I've enabled Devel, and turned on display query log, and all seems above board. the same query is shown in the query log that is printed out by `$q->__toString()`. Is it possible to get the DB handle directly so drupal can't fudge my results?